# Android pushwoosh: when launch app from notification (with trigger), how to avoid showing "complete action using" dialog

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I have a few apps implemented push notification with pushwoosh.When I send a normal push notification, it works fine. If I click the notification it brings me to the app. However, when I received a push notification with trigger, when I tried to launch the app from notification center, it asks “complete action using” dialog with a set of apps we have with pushwoosh. It basically doesn't launch the app.

I have set a filter for the launch activity in ManifestAndroid.xml

```
    <activity
                android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.xinz.app.MESSAGE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Is there a way to stop showing "complete action using" Dialog, launch the app like normal notifications, and then show the trigger pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have two activities with the "LAUNCHER" category?

As a guess you can try to remove .MESSAGE intent filter, this would let Pushwoosh SDK to try to find the default activity for your app.

Comment: It turned out to be yes. :)  I had multiple apps, their launch activities are with the same "LAUNCHER" category.  Your inference is correct.